# Discord.js v12 problem with a reaction message

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a message where users will react to and get a role. I am getting an error `Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined`. channelid is defined and the role name as well.

My code:

````
    if(blueroleID !== 0) {
    if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

    if(user.bot) return;
    if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

    if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelid){}
    if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
        await reaction.message.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(rolename)
    }
}}) ```
````

Comment: Every message only has a single `member` - the author of the message. Maybe you intended to use `reaction.users.cache` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `discord.js` `Message` class doesn't have a `members` attribute. But the `User` object from the second argument of the event listener can be used instead. It is a user object, but can be resolved to a `GuildMember` object using `Guild.member(User)`. So, you can use the following code:

```js
await reaction.message.guild.member(user).roles.add(rolename)
```